# UINavigationBar disappears before pushing view animation and appears after it. Whats wrong?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have three views and a navigation bar with my background image. When I push second view, everything goes like it should: navigation bar stays on its place with background image, just caption and buttons swipe away to the left and get replaced by "back" button and new caption for the second view. But when i push a third view, the transition goes like this: just right before animation, navigation bar disappears totally, leaving app's window background color on its place, and then, new navigation bar swipes from the right with all the ui element. and the same goes when i pop third view (push "back button"). 
Any ideas, why it is happening? It was normal before, but at the some point I noticed it start working like this.

Comment: Could you post your code? It's difficult to understand what is going on with no details.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, do you have a UISearchBar in the view you are pushing onto the stack? I was having the exact same issue as you described, it turned out it was caused by the UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController.

When creating the UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController I was calling

```
self.searchBar = [[[UISearchBar alloc] init] autorelease];//init the UISearchBarView

then somewhere further along in the code I was calling

[self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:NO];
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:NO];
```

The above two calls to "[setActive: animated:]" would layout the UISearchBar correctly for some unknown reason. I have seen this solution in many places on the interwebs. But a side effect would be that the navbar turns white when pushing a new view that had a search bar.

To fix everything I instead initialized the UISearchBar by calling:

```
self.searchBar = [[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
```

and then I deleted the two calls to "[setActive: animated:]"

This change resulted in a properly laid out search bar without the disappearing navbar.

Hope somebody will find this post useful!

Comment: thanks for reply, but no, i'm not using search bar. actually i found the problem - i was hiding and showing navigation bar consciously, because i had problems when navigating in landscape mode - after returning from full screen second view to non-fullscreen first view, status bar overlapped navigation bar. now it ok.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't pushing  a UINavigationController on top of your main navigationController?

Comment: i think no. but how can i check it?

Comment: print a description of the current navigationController in NSLog and the the memory addresses.

Comment: yeap, the addresses for navigation controllers are the same: i've loged theirs description right before pushing third view (on cell select in tableview) and right after showing third view (viewDidAppear:). `-[IVServerListViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: navcontroller: <UINavigationController: 0x274280>` and `-[IVVideoViewController viewDidAppear:]: navcontroller: <UINavigationController: 0x274280>`